# Why doesn't my formGroup validator work as expected?

Tags: angular, validation

I am tryng to do form validations and run into some issue, if I use angular email validator like this:

```
<input type="email" class="mail" email name="emailField"  [(ngModel)]="email" #emailField="ngModel">
```

and put it into form by formGroup:

```
<form  [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" >
```

```
    <input type="email" class="mail" email name="emailField"  [(ngModel)]="email" #emailField="ngModel">
        <div  class="emailinvalid" *ngIf="emailField.invalid && emailField.touched">
          <span  *ngIf="emailField.hasError('email')">
            Please enter the correct email, this email not valid.
          </span>
        </div>
          <br>
  </form>
```

in that way email-validation doesn't work, so I am looking for the way to fix it, here is my ts code:

```
export class ContactComponent  {


    myForm: FormGroup;
    email: string;
    username: string;
    surname: string;
    message: string;

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      'username':  ['', Validators.required],
      'surname': ['', Validators.required],
      'message': ['', Validators.required],

    });
  }
 }
```

`username`, `surname` and other inputs I use in my form(formGroup) above, I've just cut it off to clean the code a little in example.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You seem to have an odd mix of template and reactive form. I suggest you use a reactive form and the inbuilt validator `email` and at the same time, remove any `ngModel`.

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = fb.group({
    username:  ['', Validators.required],
    surname: ['', Validators.required],
    message: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', Validators.email]
  });
}
```

and the template would then look something like this:

```html
<form  [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" >  
  <input formControlName="username" >
  <!-- more fields here -->
  <input formControlName="email" >
  <span *ngIf="myForm.hasError('email', 'email') && myForm.get('email').touched">
    Please enter the correct email, this email not valid.
  </span>
</form>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/eXy76dF5QnUGXO8RSbpS?p=preview)** (just for clearly show the validator, I've removed the `touched`)

Comment: in the line:this.emailCtrl = this.myForm.get('email')                                          I get error :Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'.
  Property 'registerOnChange' is missing in type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: i copy exactly like in ur example, cannot find the reason thats nor working

Comment: Hmm, we can leave the variable all out then if there is an issue with it. I removed it from answer, so the template code changed a bit for the error message as well. Try now :)

Comment: Oops, had a typo as well, missing `:` at `email: ['', Validators.email]`, fixed that in my answer as well. Maybe that was the issue with your first error.

Comment: i delete it. but now there is no validation ))

Comment: i have : after email

Comment: Do you have that `span` correctly set up? It should show the error message :)

Comment: and i want ask you, herw dont import { EmailValidator } from '@angular/forms'; so here we use no inbuilt email validator ?

Comment: no, we don't import anything like that. We just import `Validators`.

Comment: that means we dont use inbuilt email validator ? if i understant that correctly,  and i copy span from your message it dosnt work anyway

Comment: Yes we use inbuilt `email` validator, it's part of `Validators` class: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

Comment: Hmm, strange it doesn't work, could you try and recreate the issue in the plunker I started, with your actual code, since I can't really help otherwise. The answer I provided should work in Angular 4, I also tried it on local project and it worked fine for me.

Comment: yeah, copy my code in plnker : http://plnkr.co/edit/WI1xoSzHXLhlfaOu6vsL?p=preview

Comment: Notice the span, it should be `<span  *ngIf="myForm.hasError('email', 'email')">` :) You were using "the old one", i.e `<span  *ngIf="emailCtrl.hasError('email')">` which won't work now when we removed `emailCtrl`

Comment: oh really, now it works, thank you bro, you help me a lot =))

Comment: Oh great! I was already scratching my head wondering what possibly could be wrong. Phew, glad to hear it worked! Have a nice day and haaappy coding! :)

Comment: but i really interesting why line : this.emailCtrl = this.myForm.get('email')                   work in plunker and doesnt on my pc

Comment: I tried that btw. It works if you declare it as `emailCtrl: any` instead of `emailCtrl: FormControl`, so it seems, at least it stops complaining then :)

Comment: yeah it works :D can i ask you  last question ?)) how long have you learned angular 2 ?

Answer (score 6):

You can have a validator.ts file

```
const pureEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

export const regexValidators = {
  phone: '[\+][0-9() ]{7,}$',
  email: pureEmail,
};
```

And use in your components like:

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
   'username':  ['', Validators.required],
   'surname': ['', Validators.required],
   'message': ['', Validators.required],
   'email':   ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.validators.email)]]    
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want to use inbuilt email validator dude))

Comment: Note Angular email validator accepts an email like "ryan@example", perhaps because "ryan@localhost" could be valid.  This is using EMAIL_REGEXP from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ffb6b2fb56d9ffcb051284965dd538629ea9687a/src/ng/directive/input.js#L16.

Either way, sometimes it makes sense to use your own regex.  The `pureEmail` regex does not accept "ryan@example" as a valid email address, which I think is a good thing.

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer. The inbuilt Validators.email validator doesn't validate general email addresses properly as shown with the ryan@example here. The regex validator validates all addresses properly. Thanks Eduardo.

Answer (score 1):

```
Validators.pattern (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
```

The above pattern works fine for me as `Validators.email` validates till we enter a `@ .post` that it is making the field as valid.